# Spring Security with Keycloak redirect to login even with antmatcher permit

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I have a spring boot application, which should be read by everybody. The other operations of this API, however, should only be executed by users with the role `ADMIN`. For this purpose, I employ Keycloak as an authorization server. The security configuration looks like this.

```
package de.longuyen.csquoteservice.config;

import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/quote/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

And the this is the important content part of application.properties

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://domain.de/keycloak/auth
keycloak.realm=realm
keycloak.resource=client_id
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

Every time I try to access the URL `/quote` with a GET I get redirected to Keycloak's login site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which url's are accessible to everyone? and which url's are accessible only to ADMIN?

Comment: The url `quote/**` should be accessed by everyone for the http method `GET`. The same url `quote/**` should be accessed only by admin for every other http method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, This should work.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/quote/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/quote/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Comment: I can access the URLs with get now. However the other methods are not allowed and I get a HTTP status 403 (the token is still alive). I thought I might be the problem with the role so I did this `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/quote/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`.

However, it still does not work. Do you have an Idea? (Nevermind, it was CSRF. Thank you very much)